# How can I print my git tags in Capistrano as part of my deploy task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, capistrano

I've set up Capistrano to ask me which git tag I want to deploy:

```
# deploy.rb
set(:branch) { Capistrano::CLI.ui.ask('Tag to deploy:') }
```

This works as expected - if I specify `v0.75` it will deploy that tag.

However, I'd love it if I could print out the list of my tags before I get asked which one to deploy, with something like this:

```
git tag -n | tac | head -n 10
```

How can I execute and print the result of the above shell command in capistrano, before being prompted for the tag to deploy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that there's no magic required. The following will do it nicely:

```
set :branch do
  puts `git tag -n | tac | head -n 10`
  Capistrano::CLI.ui.ask('Tag to deploy:')
end
```